# Columns(i).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft gives me error

Tags: vba, excel

So, I'm using 
`Columns(i).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft` to delete empty columns after filter copying them from another sheet. And it worked well until recently when it started to give me this error :

> runtime error 1004

Anyone knows whats that about?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the value of  i when it errors?

Comment: If you are deleting columns based on an ordinal columns index number (`i`) work backwards from right-to-left.

Comment: Jeeped thank you for the tip.. I shall try it :)

Comment: Post your macro - it will be easier to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This line seems correct but you should have to check your "i".Please check by pressing F8 Key.

It would be provide exact place of error..